# How to multiply two 3d numpy arrays along some particular axis?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Suppose we have two numpy arrays: `A` with shape `(n,p,q)`, `B` with shape `(n,q,r)`.

How to multiply them to get an array `C` with shape `(n,p,r)`? I mean keep axis 0 and multiply them by axis 1 and 2.

I know it can be computed by:
`C = np.stack([np.dot(a[i], b[i]) for i in range(A.shape[0])])`

But does there exist a numpy function which can be used to compute it directly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you can do [`np.einsum`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.einsum.html):

```
# sample data
n,p,q,r = 2,3,4,5
A = np.zeros((n,p,q))
B = np.zeros((n,p,r))

out = np.einsum('npq,nqr->npr',A,B)

out.shape
# (2, 3, 5)
```

Comment: `B = np.zeros((n,p,r))` should be `B = np.zeros((n,q,r))`?